# Переклад вірша Heinrich Heine «Ein Fichtenbaum steht einsam» українською

Tags: переклад, from-german

В школі ми вивчали вірш Генріха Гейне «Ein Fichtenbaum steht einsam»:

> Ein Fichtenbaum steht einsam
>   Im Norden auf kahler Höh';
>   Ihn schläfert; mit weißer Decke
>   Umhüllen ihn Eis und Schnee.

В перекладі Леоніда Первомайського - *кедр*:

> Самотній **кедр** на стромині
>   В північній стоїть стороні,
>   І кригою, й снігом укритий,
>   Дрімає і мріє вві сні.

А в перекладі Степана Чарнецького - *ялиця*:

> Глядить сумна **ялиця**
>   На зимні береги;
>   Над нею студінь злиться,
>   Окутують сніги.

У німецькому оригіналі — *сосна*.

Таким чином, ми отримали *сосну*, *кедр* та *ялицю*.

В чому причина різних перекладів і чи є інші подібні приклади в українських перекладах?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Der Fichtenbaum** — це *ялина* або *ялиця* (<sub>рос.</sub>*пихта*).

**Der Baum** — іменник чоловічого роду.

Сам вірш Гейне — про кохання, яке не склалося.
Друга строфа вказує, що *«**він** мріє про Пальму»*:

> **Er traeumt von einer Palme,**
>     Die, fern im Morgenland,
>     Einsam und schweigend trauert
>     Auf brennender Felsenwand.

Але використання назви дерева жіночого роду (*ялина* або *ялиця*) трошки зміщує акценти, і **вірш про кохання** «чоловічого» Fichtenbaum до «жіночої» Palme перетворюється на **вірш про самотність** Ялини, якій **хочеться бути** Пальмою (або якимось чином отримати долю Пальми, жити у теплих краях тощо).

---

Тому:

- З точки зору дослівного перекладу — *ялина* або *ялиця*;
- З точки зору точності смислової передачі — має бути дерево чоловічого роду. Наприклад, *кедр*.

В обох випадках ми при перекладі щось втрачаємо. І різні автори перекладів вже самі мусили приймати рішення стосовно того, що́ варто втратити, а що́ — зберегти.

---

**Update.** Шановний @Artemix зазначає у коментарі:

> До речі, читав гарну статтю про традиції (щоправда, російського) перекладу, в якій наводилися приклади того що хоча гендер людей у перекладі передається правильно, на гендер інших істот або навіть речей (наприклад у казці це може бути годинник) майже ніколи не звертають уваги. Найбільш відомими і водночас некоректними перекладами є: Багіра з "Мауглі" (взагалі повинен бути Багір - це опозиція Шер-Хану, лицар проти розбійника), Сова з Вінні-Пуха (повинен бути Філін - недовчений учень - до появи Кенги у лісі була виключно чоловіча дитяча компанія), Соня з божевільного чаювання в "Алісі" Льюіса Керола
>   [Гендер сказочных и мифологических персонажей англоязычной литературы в русских переводах](http://magazines.russ.ru/voplit/2009/2/eli12.html)

У статті також згадується думка І.Чистової щодо вірша Гейне.

Comment: підтвердження вашої відповіді випадково знайшла в посібнику Є.Д.Чак "Барви нашого слова" (Київ, "Радянська школа", 1989)

Comment: Ще трошки не за темою, але Є.Д.Чак описує схожу ситуацію з перекладом "Пісні про блоху" з "Фауста". В перекладі Миколи Лукаша  звучить так: "*Жив цар колись у давнину, Й була в нього блоха; Мов рідную дитину, Він ту блоху кохав. Велів кравця позвати. Прийшов к ньому кравець: "Поший мерщій паняті Штанці і жупанець!*" Цар на цьому не спинився: "*Міністром стала скоро - Аж сяють ордени...*"  Блоха жіночого роду, а їй шиють "штанці і жупанець", чоловіче вбрання; її роблять міністром, а цю посаду займали тільки чоловіки.

Comment: **Продовження попереднього коментаря.** Річ у тім, як зазначає Є.Д.Чак, що німецькою мовою *блоха* буде *Floh* - іменник чоловічого роду. Звичайно, він символізує особу чоловічої статі,і, природно, атрибути чоловічого вбрання цілком відповідають ситуації. А в українській мові відповідник до німецького *Floh* тільки один - *блоха*, синонімів немає. Тому доводиться задовольнятися ним.

Answer (score 2):

Це ж поезія, ні? Яка різниця, про який саме вид хвойних писав Гайне? Візьмемо Єсєніна «Белая берёза под моим окном», чи знаєте ви, що [існує 120 видів берези](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0), про який саме вид із цих ста двадцяти писав поет? А тепер уявіть саамів, для яких береза – це єдине дерево, що росте в їхній країні, у них немає инших дерев окрім берез, їхне слово «дерево» й означає «будь-який вид наших берез», а ще у них є спеціялізовані назви для кожного їх виду, то який з них має обрати перекладач Єсєніна саамською?

Хочу зазначити, що *Fichtenbaum* – це саме ***ялина***. «Сосна» німецькою – *Kiefer*, *Kiefernbaum*, рідше *Föhre*, *Föhrenbaum*. Отже, ваші сумніви безпідставні.

А ще цікава штука: німецьке *Fichte* є словом, з якого походить наше *піхта*, то от українська Вікіпедія й перенаправляє вас автоматично при запиті «піхта» на статтю [«Ялиця»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F), можете самі спробувати.